# Angular ui tour error with requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am using angular ui tour with require js and trying to load the library but getting the below error. I have included all the files related to ui tour and added the dependency in the angular module also. Can anybody help me to find  out the solution.

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mm-webapp-material due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bm.uiTour due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'bm.uiTour' is not available!
```

============================

```
["ez-ng": "components/ez-ng/dist/ez-ng.min",
        "hotkeys": "components/angular-hotkeys/build/hotkeys.min",
        "hone": "components/hone/hone",
        "tether": "components/tether/dist/js/tether",
        "angular-scroll": "components/angular-scroll/angular-scroll",
        "angular-bind-html": "components/angular-bind-html-compile/angular-bind-html-compile",
        "angular-uitour": "components/angular-ui-tour/dist/angular-ui-tour",]


=========================

["ez-ng": {
            deps: ["angular"]
        },
        "hotkeys": {
            deps: ["angular"]
        },
        "hone": {
            deps: ["angular"]
        },
        "tether": {
            deps: ["angular"]
        },
        "angular-scroll": {
            deps: ["angular"]
        },
        "angular-bind-html": {
            deps: ["angular"]
        },
        "angular-uitour": {
            deps: ["angular", "angular-sanitize", "angular-bootstrap", "ez-ng", "angular-scroll", "hotkeys", "angular-bind-html", "tether", "hone"]
        }
]
```